# Electric field and flux through a spherical surface inside an uneven hollow charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Consider a uniformly charged shell and two concentric spherical Gaussian surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$. ($S_1$ radius is greater than charged shell and $S_2$ radius is less than that of charged shell.) 
We know   that the net flux through $S_2$ is zero. Now, if I change the distribution by making some areas with lots of charge and other areas with lesser amount of charge (uneven distribution),  the net flux through $S_1$ remains the same and the net flux through $S_2$ is still zero (as it does not enclose a charge.)

So my question is - since net flux through $S_2$ is zero, does that mean electric field is zero inside region of unevenly distributed charged shell? If there is net electric field inside the shell then why is flux not zero.

Please correct me if am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss's Law states that, $$\int_S E.dA=\frac{q}{\epsilon_o}$$

The $q$, here, is the charge enclosed ***inside*** the Gaussian surface. You are right when you say that the net flux through $S_2$ is zero, but that only means that the net flux due to **enclosed charges** in $S_2$ is zero. You cannot make implications about the Electric Field due to an external charge distribution using Gauss's Law.

The net flux due to charges which are not inside the Gaussian surface is always zero, but this doesn't imply that that the field due to those charges should be zero at those points.

You could also consider this case, because it is somewhat similar.

If your Gaussian surface is a sphere centered at say, $x=a$, and  if there is a charge at $x=0$, the net flux due to that charge would be zero through the sphere, because the sphere doesn't contain the charge. But you would obviously have a non zero electric field in that region because of the same charge.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a surface has zero electric flux through it, it does not mean that the electric field will be zero throughout it. What this means is that the field lines that go into the surface must come out of it at some other point. Thus, if $\mathbf E\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf S$ is nonzero at some point in the surface, there must be some other point in the surface where $\mathbf E\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf S$ has opposite sign, so that the overall integral vanishes.

[image]

<sup>Image source: [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CampelectricoenunVolumen.JPG)</sup>

In your case (a hollow, but otherwise arbitrary charge distribution), the electric field can indeed be nonzero. (In fact, it can correspond to *any* electrostatic potential which satisfies the Laplace equation $\nabla^2\varphi=0$.)